# Docker run causing kernel panic

Tags: linux-mint, docker, crash

I'm trying to run Docker under a Linux Mint 17.3, and every step works fine(pull, rm, images, etc), but whenever I try to run any containers, my computer freezes totally (though the music keeps playing) and the only solution is to hard reboot it.

Kernel version:

```
$ uname -a

Linux computer-name 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Docker version:

```
$ docker version

Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

From `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226185.904735] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[3316]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226185.931749] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[3316]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226185.971708] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[22841]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.034451] aufs au_opts_verify:1612:docker[3311]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.128366] device veth5222fce entered promiscuous mode
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.128478] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth5222fce: link is not ready
Nov 19 15:12:30 computer-name NetworkManager[1074]: message repeated 4 times: [ <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted]
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name NetworkManager[1074]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5ee7fbb, iface: veth5ee7fbb)
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name NetworkManager[1074]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5ee7fbb, iface: veth5ee7fbb): no ifupdown configuration found.
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name NetworkManager[1074]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5ee7fbb: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name NetworkManager[1074]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5222fce, iface: veth5222fce)
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name NetworkManager[1074]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5222fce, iface: veth5222fce): no ifupdown configuration found.
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.147809] eth0: renamed from veth5ee7fbb
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name avahi-daemon[1068]: Withdrawing workstation service for veth5ee7fbb.
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name NetworkManager[1074]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5222fce: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name NetworkManager[1074]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5ee7fbb, iface: veth5ee7fbb)
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.173293] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth5222fce: link becomes ready
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.173339] docker0: port 1(veth5222fce) entered forwarding state
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.173371] docker0: port 1(veth5222fce) entered forwarding state
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.173406] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): docker0: link becomes ready
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.221389] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000011
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.221434] IP: [<ffffffff8134118d>] aa_path_name+0x4d/0x350
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.221464] PGD 13adc1067 PUD 138823067 PMD 0
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.221489] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.221507] Modules linked in: veth xt_nat xt_tcpudp cdc_acm xt_addrtype xt_conntrack ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack bridge stp llc aufs ctr ccm rfcomm binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec dell_wmi sparse_keymap snd_hwdep snd_pcm intel_rapl iosf_mbi dell_laptop x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_seq_midi dcdbas intel_powerclamp coretemp arc4 snd_seq_midi_event i8k snd_rawmidi kvm_intel kvm snd_seq ath9k dm_multipath uvcvideo ath9k_common scsi_dh ath9k_hw crct10dif_pclmul ath3k videobuf2_vmalloc btusb crc32_pclmul videobuf2_memops ath videobuf2_core mac80211 v4l2_common rtsx_usb_ms videodev ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel memstick aes_x86_64 media lrw gf128mul bluetooth glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd cfg80211 joydev snd_seq_device serio_raw snd_timer snd mei_me soundcore mei lpc_ich shpchp mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb hid_generic usbhid hid amdkfd amd_iommu_v2 radeon i915 ahci i2c_algo_bit ttm psmouse r8169 libahci mii drm_kms_helper drm video wmi
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222117] CPU: 2 PID: 10037 Comm: run.sh Tainted: G        W      3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222154] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 7520/0DNMM8, BIOS A10 05/13/2013
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222184] task: ffff880104d893a0 ti: ffff880004084000 task.ti: ffff880004084000
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222214] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8134118d>]  [<ffffffff8134118d>] aa_path_name+0x4d/0x350
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222249] RSP: 0018:ffff880004087898  EFLAGS: 00010206
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222271] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000010004 RCX: ffff8800040879c8
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222299] RDX: ffff8802568e2000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff880004087a78
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222328] RBP: ffff880004087918 R08: ffff880004087960 R09: 0000000000000000
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222356] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000010004 R12: ffff8802568e2000
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222384] R13: 0000000000002000 R14: ffff880004087a78 R15: ffff880004087a78
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222413] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88025f280000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222445] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222469] CR2: 0000000000000011 CR3: 0000000004e57000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222500] Stack:
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222510]  ffff880003626d00 000000000459a9fa 0000000000000000 00ffffff812ea59f
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222545]  ffff8800040879c8 ffff880004087960 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222580]  ffff880004087908 ffff8800040879f8 ffff880250053000 ffff8802549cdc30
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222616] Call Trace:
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222631]  [<ffffffff8134ab10>] path_name+0x60/0x140
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222654]  [<ffffffff8134b012>] aa_path_perm+0xa2/0x130
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222678]  [<ffffffff8134825f>] common_perm+0x5f/0x110
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222701]  [<ffffffff8134833b>] common_perm_cond+0x2b/0x30
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222726]  [<ffffffff81348383>] apparmor_inode_getattr+0x43/0x50
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222752]  [<ffffffff813083b0>] security_inode_getattr+0x20/0x30
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222779]  [<ffffffff811f125e>] vfs_getattr+0x1e/0x40
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222807]  [<ffffffffc0a17aff>] vfsub_update_h_iattr+0x6f/0x80 [aufs]
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222836]  [<ffffffff811f6983>] ? __lookup_hash+0x33/0x40
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222862]  [<ffffffff811f77a6>] ? lookup_one_len+0xe6/0x140
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222894]  [<ffffffffc0a17df0>] vfsub_lookup_one_len+0x40/0x50 [aufs]
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222928]  [<ffffffffc0a1ebb2>] au_sio_lkup_one+0x72/0x90 [aufs]
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222959]  [<ffffffffc0a1b9dd>] ? au_wh_test+0x5d/0xd0 [aufs]
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.222988]  [<ffffffff817b4cb6>] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x37
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.223015]  [<ffffffffc0a1eec5>] au_lkup_dentry+0x2f5/0x500 [aufs]
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.223045]  [<ffffffff811cfd01>] ? __kmalloc+0x141/0x280
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.223070]  [<ffffffff817b4e0b>] ? __down_interruptible+0x7/0x1f
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.223102]  [<ffffffffc0a27266>] aufs_lookup+0xd6/0x280 [aufs]
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.224571]  [<ffffffff811f5f8d>] lookup_real+0x1d/0x50
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.225949]  [<ffffffff811fac6a>] do_last+0x92a/0x1190
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.227421]  [<ffffffff811f9051>] ? path_init+0xc1/0x470
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.228783]  [<ffffffff811fb550>] path_openat+0x80/0x600
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.230109]  [<ffffffff811cf1f1>] ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x1a1/0x220
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.231435]  [<ffffffff811fd58a>] do_filp_open+0x3a/0x90
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.232598]  [<ffffffff8120a1c7>] ? __alloc_fd+0xa7/0x130
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.233624]  [<ffffffff811eb5b9>] do_sys_open+0x129/0x280
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.234606]  [<ffffffff811eb72e>] SyS_open+0x1e/0x20
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.235598]  [<ffffffff817b6dcd>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.236525] Code: e6 01 48 83 ec 58 44 8b 2d 55 23 95 00 48 89 4d a0 4c 89 45 a8 4c 89 4d 90 48 c7 45 b8 00 00 00 00 40 88 75 9f 41 29 c5 48 8b 07 <f6> 40 11 40 0f 85 59 01 00 00 f6 c3 08 0f 85 b0 00 00 00 44 89
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.238551] RIP  [<ffffffff8134118d>] aa_path_name+0x4d/0x350
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.239508]  RSP <ffff880004087898>
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.240449] CR2: 0000000000000011
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.246772] ---[ end trace 4e20d9a851b6ce1a ]---
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name avahi-daemon[1068]: Withdrawing workstation service for veth5222fce.
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name NetworkManager[1074]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5222fce, iface: veth5222fce)
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.289211] docker0: port 1(veth5222fce) entered disabled state
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.291316] device veth5222fce left promiscuous mode
Nov 19 16:14:59 computer-name kernel: [226186.291323] docker0: port 1(veth5222fce) entered disabled state
Nov 19 16:15:00 computer-name avahi-daemon[1068]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface docker0.IPv6 with address fe80::5484:7aff:fefe:9799.
Nov 19 16:15:00 computer-name avahi-daemon[1068]: New relevant interface docker0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Nov 19 16:15:00 computer-name avahi-daemon[1068]: Registering new address record for fe80::5484:7aff:fefe:9799 on docker0.*.
```

I rebooted it using the SysReq keys(`alt+fn+printScreen` on my machine):

```
Nov 19 16:17:01 computer-name CRON[18768]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov 19 16:21:21 computer-name kernel: [226567.079427] SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
Nov 19 16:21:27 computer-name kernel: [226573.640089] SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
Nov 19 16:21:32 computer-name kernel: [226578.834370] SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
Nov 19 16:21:47 computer-name kernel: [226593.378254] SysRq : Emergency Sync
Nov 19 16:21:47 computer-name kernel: [226593.386246] Emergency Sync complete
Nov 19 16:21:53 computer-name kernel: [226599.403632] SysRq : Emergency Remount R/O
Nov 19 16:22:20 computer-name rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="1027" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Nov 19 16:22:20 computer-name rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
Nov 19 16:22:20 computer-name rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Nov 19 16:22:20 computer-name kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Nov 19 16:22:20 computer-name kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Nov 19 16:22:20 computer-name kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Nov 19 16:22:20 computer-name kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.19.0-32-generic (buildd@lgw01-43) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 (Ubuntu 3.19.0-32.37~14.04.1-generic 3.19.8-ckt7)
```

Since that I installed this Mint image some months ago, it should be perfectly capable of running Docker, but I don't know what to do about this error. I'm trying to run an `apt-get upgrade` now (should take a while), but after that, I don't know what to do.

Comment: @countermode the hello world runs fine, but no other containers does. I've tried with the Jenkins, sonar and MariaDB ones, and they all completely freeze my computer. I believe that docker worked on a previous Ubuntu installation, but I don't recall testing it further than the hello world once I got it installed.

Comment: "BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference" almost always means you've found a kernel bug. I'm not sure if Mint provides newer kernels somewhere (e.g., in a backports repository, etc.)—that'd be the first thing to try. And of course you should report the bug to them, if that's their current stable kernel. (If you have to work around it, both apparmor and aufs are in the backtrace—so you could try a different Docker storage backend, for example. Or disable apparmor, of course that'll decrease security.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was following [this tutorial](https://mintguide.org/system/561-install-linux-kernel-4-4-lts-on-linux-mint.html) to install the 4.4.0 kernel on Mint. And reinstalling docker (a bunch of times, since I had a corrupted previous configuration), because I had installed it using a one-liner and a script, and not followed the install instructions on Docker official website, I believe.

So now I could run it with:

> $ uname -r

```
4.4.0-040400-generic
```

> $ docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 21:44:32 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 21:44:32 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Not exactly a solution for the problem as I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working, but it's working now (tested with the ubuntu and sonar images, both worked fine).